# asp.net core 3.1 change route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-3.1

Is there an easy way to change the route of asp.net core 3.1 controller ?

Currently I have controller `PicVideosController` URL: ...\picvideos... and I was asked to modify the url to ...\picturesvideos...

I added a route on the controller side :

```
[Route("picturesvideos")]
public class PicVideosController : Controller
```

get an error `AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: Main.Controllers.PicVideosController.Pay (Main) Main.Controllers.PicVideosController.Completed (Main)` still seems like it is looking at the original url

Comment: Firstly, API controllers should be marked `[ApiController, Route("picturesvideos")]`, secondly, are you setting the `[Route]` on the endpoints of the controllers.

Comment: You should really just C&P the entire controller.

Comment: @Andy this is not ApiController

Comment: This post needs more details and clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
[Route("picturesvideos/[action]")]
public class PicVideosController : Controller
{
[Route("/")]
[Route("~/picturesvideos")]
[Route("~/picturesvideos/index")]
public IActionResult Index()
....
```

Comment: Thanks, now when I load, I need to type picturesvideos/index where before it would just load automatically index and not display in the url index would be just http://...picvideos/ and now i need to type http://...picturesvideos/index  (how can I load index without display index in the URL?) as before?

Comment: I made some changes. try and let me know if it work for you.